# python: pd.rolling_std function result is different from the standard deviation calculator

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, standard-deviation

There is dataframe as following, I want to compute the close column: volatility, for exaple window=2, namely two rows's volatility. I

```
   Date      close
2010-06-09    3160.0
2010-06-10    3180.0
2010-06-11    3215.0
2010-06-14    3255.0
```

I  used the following code which use the function:

```
stdDeviation = pd.rolling_std(df['Close'],window=2)
stdDeviation.head(4)
```

The result is:

```
      Date
2010-06-09          NaN
2010-06-10    14.142136
2010-06-11    24.748737
2010-06-14    28.284271
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

but when calculate the standard deviation by the calculator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

I found the first two numbers: 3160, 3180, the standard deviation of these two number is 10 which is different from 14.142136 which calculated by the function.pd.rolling_std.

Could you guy tell me more about the function rolling_std, what's the clacualtor of this function in detail. why is different, is there something wrong in my question . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas by default calculates the sample standard deviation. The denominator for the sample standard deviation has a correction factor so we divide the sum of squares by `n-1` instead of `n`. 1 here is the lost degrees of freedom due to the sample mean. If you want to get the same result, you can pass `ddof=0` to rolling_std which will give you 10 as the result.

```
stdDeviation = pd.rolling_std(df['Close'], window=2, ddof=0)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I want to calculate the volatility of close which is the close price of stock. I mean which one is correct: sample std or std?

Comment: You are calculating from a sample of returns so I think you should use sample standard deviation. A few pages I looked at seem to agree: http://www.macroption.com/historical-volatility-calculation/